# In Extjs, how to get a reference to the parent app?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Is there a a one liner that will give me a reference to the current controller's parent application without using the name of the parent app? Some thing like `this.getParent`? What I am ultimately trying to do is

```
this.parentapp.getController('aChildsController').someMethod();
```

Comment: See this: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?179340-Why-does-this.getApplication().getController(-MainController-).testFunction()-fail

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can simply use `this.getApplication()`, or even shorter `this.app`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.lookupReference('referenceId').up()
this will return immediate ancestor Container.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the following in extjs5, but this works in extjs6 classic:

Ext.app.Application.instance.getController(...).

This allows you to get a reference to the application without knowing the application name.